# How to display a view when webview is touched continously for 10 sec?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview, touch

I am displaying a pub or a pdf file in webview. But I am not able to detect the touch on the webview.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

above method is called when I touch any text of the pdf or pub file. How can I detect the click on the webview which is displaying a pdf or a pub file.

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://dblog.com.au"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:request];
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 6.0;
[self.webView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];
[longPressGestureRecognizer release];

}

- (void)handleLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
NSLog(@"Long press detected");
 }

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
return YES;
}
```

Please check it, did I make any mistake?

Comment: Looks OK you have to add <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> to youre .h, and set longPressGestureRecognizer.delegate = self..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 10.0;
[self.webView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];
[longPressGestureRecognizer release];
```

And then:

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"Long press detected");
}
```

EDIT:

Add this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
return YES;
}
```

But pressing same place for 10 seconds is a really long time... the default value for a long press is 0.4 seconds. Keep in mind that if the finger is dragged it is no longer a long press..

Comment: @Larsaronen : is there any way for me to to determine the coordinates at the point touched?

Comment: Yes there is CGPoint tapLocation = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.webView];

Comment: @Larsaronen : Thanks i was able to determine it.